# Automatic Quicken Spell at level 21? [Neverwinter Nights]

Tags: neverwinter-nights

http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_quicken_spell

> Prerequisite: 21st level, quicken spell, spellcraft 30, ability to cast 9th level spells

Okay, but how. I thought your skill rank cap is Level+3, which would be 24 at 21st level? Does this feat instead use a modified rank value instead of a base value? Is it possible to get Automatic Quicken Spell at level 21?

Comment: This may be a holdover from tabletop dungeons and dragons, where 'Epic' feats all require you to be 21st level, even if the other requirements would not be achievable at that level.

Answer (score 2):

[Epic feats](http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Epic_feat) (like [Automatic Quicken Spell](http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_quicken_spell)) require a character to be level 21. This is the definition of an epic feat. This does not indicate that they can be chosen at that level. You still have to meet other requirements.

Automatic Quicken Spell requires 30 ranks in spellcraft. If it is a [class skill](http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Class_skill) this requires a level 27 character. It is not possible to achieve this at level 21.